I need to have multiple contact forms on a website using Node.js
I am creating a website for a restaurant where there will be multiple contact forms.
I am using Node.js with Express and Nodemailer dependencies to send the forms. I have my main contact form in the footer working and sending perfectly - simple email, name, message inputs.
What I need is an additional form - separate page - for private event bookings/inquiries. This will be more thorough and have more fields. Some will be radio buttons to chose from a set of options, some will be text inputs.
I just need to know if I need to make a server2.js file or if I can handle both forms in one server file. I would think create a separate server file as it would be messy not to, no?
As well, in my main app.js file, I would just create a new XML variable and basically do the same thing correct?
This is my contact form html
 <section id="hm-contact">
        <div class="form-container">
            <form class="contact-form">
                <h2>CONTACT</h2>
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name"></br>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"></br>
                <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"></br>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea></br>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="map">
            <img src="/img/HmMapImg.png" alt="Map with El Tres location">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-info">
            <p class="hours">Hours</p>
            <div class="weekday-hours">
                <p class="week-days">Tuesday - Thursday</p>
                <p class="week-hrs">5pm - 10pm</p>
            </div>
            <div class="weekend-hours">
                <p class="weekend-days">Friday &amp; Saturday</p>
                <p class="frisat-hrs">5pm - 1am</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tequila-night">
                <p class="tequila-day">Half Price Tequila Fridays</p>
                <p class="tequila-hrs">9pm - 11pm</p>
            </div>
            <div class="location">
                <p class="address">269 Red River Rd.</p>
                <p class="city">Thunder Bay, ON P7B 1A9</p>
                <p class="phone">(807) 344-3443</p>
            </div>
        </div>

This is my server.js so far (of course I will be putting sensitive info in a .env file, but for dev and testing it's here for now until launch (which speaking of .env, will I need two files or can I use one .env for both emails?)
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'mail.myntbranding.com',
        port: 465,
        auth: {
            user:'email@email.com',
            pass: 'password'
        }
    })

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to: 'email@email',
        subject: `Message from ${req.body.email}: ${req.body.subject}`,
        text: req.body.message
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send('error');
        }else{
            console.log('Email sent:' + info.response);
            res.send('success')
        }
    });
})

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

And then this is my app.js
const contactForm = document.querySelector('.contact-form');

let name = document.getElementById('name');
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let subject = document.getElementById('subject');
let message = document.getElementById('message');

contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let formData = {
        name: name.value,
        email: email.value,
        subject: subject.value,
        message: message.value
    }

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function(){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        if(xhr.responseText == 'success') {
            alert('Email Sent');
            name.value = '';
            email.value = '';
            subject.value = '';
            message.value = '';
        }else{
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    }

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));

});

I haven't tried anything yet, I want to seek out some advice and then see whatsup when I test it out. I've also been looking for tutorials but I can't find anything on how to handle more than one contact form with node.

You should be able to handle multiple contact forms using a single server.js file. You would just have to create different routes for each form.
A few steps to follow:

Store sensitive information in a single .env file.
Add a new POST route for the event booking form in server.js
Create the corresponding HTML and JavaScript for the new form.

The route could look something like this:
app.post('/event-booking', (req, res) => {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ /* transporter config here */ });
    const mailOptions = { /* mail options based on req.body */ };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => { /* handle response */ });
});

Then when you do your AJAX operation, ensure this points to the handler you want:
xhr.open('POST', '/event-booking');

